# How to assess selected response distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit, gamma-distribution

I am trying to predict the impact of readmission events (continuous) and type of readmission (medical, surgical, other) on total hospital costs. Because costs are skewed by nature, I am using a Gamma distribution with a log link function. Below is the model:

```
PROC GENMOD data = abc;
  class type (ref='medical') gender (ref='F')/param=ref;
  model cost = event type age gender /dist=gamma link=log type3; 
run;
```

Since the last time I posted this question, I did some more research on this topic and found:

1. Estimate alpha (shape) and beta (scale) parameters of the distribution and run goodness of fit test.
2. Check the deviance and chi-square value to assess model fit.

My question is: **How would one validate whether the chosen distribution is indeed correct?**

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Questions that are purely about programming/carrying out routine procedures in statistical packages are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  If you have an underlying statistical question, edit your post to emphasize it.  If your question is indeed about programming, try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or check out the list of [internet resources for statistical packages](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that we maintain

Comment: The question now seems to be not about SAS, but about how to assess the proposed response distribution. I think this is suitably on topic now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a simpler approach.  Fit the cost data to a gamma distribution and then apply a goodness-of-fit test.  I you can't reject the gamma distribution then use it in the model.  Now find a transformation that makes the data approximately normal.  Then apply simple linear regression to the transformed data.  You would not need to use a generalized linear model.  In the generalized linear model, why did you choose the log function to be the link function?

Comment: Unlike OLS with a log-transformed dependent variable, the use of generalized linear model with log-link function preserves the standard interpretation of regression coefficients in terms of the effect of an independent variable on average costs. Using OLS with log-transformed dependent variable and back transforming introduces a bias, so I used gamma distribution with log link.

Comment: As suggested, I fit the cost data two ways and checked deviance (GOF test)  to determine which distribution fits best my data.                                               1) gamma with log link gives deviance 33.9002 and chi-square 0.223             2) gamma with identity link gives deviance 34.29 and chi-square 0.23. Although both the models are good, because deviance is less for gamma with log link, I believe that is a better pick. Any thoughts??

Comment: What matters is the conditional distribution of the response. This appears to suggest fitting the marginal distribution.